# Cannot import files in MongoDB -Compass

Tags: deb, mongodb

I just installed the MongoDB Compass downloading the latest stable deb file (1.21.2 amd64) in my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS VM.

The problem is, when I want to import a JSON to a collection, it does not work: The text below the import windows "Importing documents..." does not change.

Everything else with Compass is just fine. Do you have an idea how to fix it? May I need to change permissions somewhere?

[image]